# How to properly backport dependencies when backporting a package to PPA?

Tags: ppa, backport

I want to backport package **X** that depends on **Y**, so both packages need backporting. First, I backport Y, so it becomes something like *Y-a.b~ubuntu123*. When I now try to backport X it complains about missing dependency *Y-a.b* due to weird version comparison algorithm, which makes effectively *Y-a.b~ubuntu123* < *Y-a.b* :

> *(From debian.org)*
>
> First the initial part of each string consisting entirely of non-digit
> characters is determined. These two parts (one of which may be empty)
> are compared lexically. If a difference is found it is returned. The
> lexical comparison is a comparison of ASCII values modified so that
> all the letters sort earlier than all the non-letters and so that a
> tilde sorts before anything, even the end of a part. For example, the
> following parts are in sorted order from earliest to latest: ~~, ~~a,
> ~, the empty part, a.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes; the backported-to version has to be lower than the backported-from version in order for upgrades to work properly.  The standard solution is to add a trailing `~` to the dependency, so that it's something like `Y (>= a.b~)` rather than `Y (>= a.b)`.  You'll find that in quite a few packages in Debian and Ubuntu that have found that they care about supporting backports.

Comment: I ended up using exactly the same solution =)